# How to make an input automatically submit to a URL if the text is "13"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

i am making a website on glitch so that when you type in "13" in the input field, it automatically redirects to a URL.

this is what i have and i don't know what is wrong.

```
    <form id="myform" action="https://example.com" method="get">
      <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
    </form>

    <script>
      var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
      var form = document.getElementById("myform");
      text.onkeyup = function() {
        if (text === "13") {
          form.submit();
        }
      };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say text.value

```js
 var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
text.onkeyup = function() {
  if (text.value === "13") {
    form.submit();
  }
};
 function validateForm(){
     if(text.value!="13")
     {return false;}return true;
 }
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="https://example.com" method="get"onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
    </form>
```

Comment: it redirects me every time i put something not 13 though?

Comment: I try different numbers but it doesn't redirect. Only 13 redirects. Did u try snippet? Or it happens in your  code?

Comment: If u click enter after u wrote something it always redirects u. Because You are in form tag and enter fires submit.

Comment: oh, how could i do that? just remove <form> ?

Comment: Do u want prevent every submit without 13 ?

Comment: I edited answer then u will put onsubmit event to form that check if 13 or not

Answer (score 1):

use `if (text.value === "13")` instead of `if (text === "13")` as text is referring to input element.

```js
      var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
      var form = document.getElementById("myform");
      text.onkeyup = function() {
        if (text.value === "13") {
          form.submit();
        }
      };
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="https://example.com" method="get">
      <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.

```
let text = document.getElementById("mytext");

text.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  if (text.value === "13") {
    // Submit Form
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple get method you can use window.location.href = "https://example.com"; or window.location.replace("https://example.com");

so it will be something like this

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
<script>
      var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
      text.onkeyup = function() {
        if (text.value === "13") {
          window.location.href = "https://example.com";
        }
      };
    </script>
```